# No kali tools on Kali Linux on Raspberry Pi

Tags: kali-linux, raspberry-pi

I recently got Kali Linux on my Raspberry Pi 2 model B and I am having a lot of problems with it. The major one is that there are no penetration tools such as msfconsole, metasploit etc. When I typed msfvenom followed by the other instructions I was following from a tutorial, i got an error

> -bash: msfvenom: command not found

And similarly for all other tools. What should I do?

Answer (score 6):

The Raspberry version of Kali come with only the minimum needed to run, as stated [here](https://docs.kali.org/kali-on-arm/install-kali-linux-arm-raspberry-pi), you need to instal kali-linux-full to have access to all the tools

Ps: Kali is hard, it's not intended as a beginer distrib

Comment: alright i understood that i would need the kali-linux-full for my Pi, but does it have to be installed after installing the version that I have installed like I saw in a YouTube tutorial or is there an ARM image which i can directly download and burn to the sd card?

Answer (score 0):

To rectify this problem, you may want to either download a full version of the Kali Linux distro onto your Raspberry Pi (choosing the correct ARM-architecture model for your device) or attempt to install the software yourself.

Try to perform an **apt-cache search** at the terminal for the programs that you wish to install. If they are available in the repository, the set up can be as simple as executing an **apt-get install** and confirming you want to install it. Another alternative during the installation would be executing a simulated run to ensure there are no missing dependencies or other issues. You can do this utilizing the **-s** switch.

For example: **sudo apt-get install -s [program name]**

Granted, this could prove to be complicated overall. If you are new to Linux, then you are best off not utilizing Kali Linux to start. It is a powerful system, albeit a difficult one at times (especially if you have never utilized the tools it includes). I would advise installing a more user-friendly distro such as Linux Mint to start with. However, if compatibility is a problem, then Ubuntu tends to be the friendliest distro with a great package manager to be found in Synaptic.

Comment: Thank you, but I am not new to Linux. I appreciate your help